# What is the correct way (syntax) of combining boolean operators in python

Tags: python, unicode, integer, type-conversion

So i'm working on a simple python game (Merels). this function is supposed to let the player enter what enemy token he would like to remove but asking him again if he enters an invalid position. the "layer" variable stands for the square the position is in (a board of merels is like 3 concentric squares) and the "layer" variable stands for the position in the layer. there should be no logical flaws. on the third last line an error message pops up and that says: 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode'.

```
def playerRemove(board, removeLetter):
    print("You have scored a mill! Choose an enemy Token to remove.")
    layer=0
    print("First enter the layer. (1-3)")
    layer=raw_input()
    while layerEmpty(board, layer, removeLetter):
        print("First enter the layer. (1-3)")
        layer=raw_input()

    position=9
    layer=int(layer)
    position=int(position)
    while board[layer][position]!=removeLetter or isMill(board, computerLetter):
        print("Now enter the position. (1-8)")
        position=raw_input()
```

i've had this problem many times but so far the solution was to convert the variable into an integer with an expression like

```
x=int(x)
```

but somehow this isnt working here.

Comment: Do you need a position=int(position) at the very end of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop you're correctly doing `position = int(position)`, so you successfully enter into the loop, but then within the loop you ask for a new `position`, at the line:

```
position = raw_input()
```

Change this to:

```
position = int(raw_input())
```